# Repeat a function until conditions are met in r using a while loop

Tags: r, function, if-statement, while-loop, boolean

This may not be the most efficient way for doing this, but I've created a code for a fruit machine (that works), from the help of a book (not sure if I can share the title, but it is very good for noobs). However this code is very simple, it runs a function that calls two other functions, in order:

1. `pull()` simulates the wheel mechanism by randomly selecting characters from a pre-determined vector.
2. `prize()` analyses the response from `pull()` to add a value to the symbols by using a lookup table.

The code works, but I wanted to modify it so that the code runs until it reaches the jackpot which is three diamonds; `"DD"`. I also wanted it to quantify all other responses until it reaches this target, so I tried a while loop, which does not seem to produce anything:

```
 play2 <- function(){
  response <- pull()

  # I put the while loop straight after calling the first function,
  # hoping that if the condition is not met, then the first function
  # runs again, creating a new "response" until conditions are met.

  while (sum(response == "DD") != 3) {

  # I set the condition so that if the jackpot is not achieved, the 
  # while loop causes the other responses to be investigated. It 
  # it determines this by counting booleans. 

    # The following assignments are designed to begin the count for how
    # many responses that are considered prizes occur, and how often no
    # prize occurs.

    cherry_prize <- 0
    B_prize <- 0
    BB_prize <- 0
    BBB_prize <- 0
    seven_prize <- 0
    no_prize <- 0

    if ("C" %in% response){
      cherry_prize <- cherry_prize + 1



      # A cherry prize occurs if any "C" is returned. The following
      # statements will asses the other non-jackpot three of a kinds.

    }
    else if (sum(response == "B") != 3) {
      B_prize <- B_prize + 1
    }
    else if (sum(response == "BB") != 3) {
      BB_prize <- BB_prize + 1
    }
    else if (sum(response == "BBB") != 3) {
      BBB_prize <- BBB_prize + 1
    }
    else if (sum(response == "7") != 3) {
      seven_prize <- seven_prize + 1
    }
    else {
      no_prize <- no_prize + 1
    }
  }

  # After the jackpot is achieved, the number of other prizes (or lack
  # thereof) that were returned are quantified, prior to the jackpot 
  # were won. The jackpot triplicate would then also be returned and
  # quantified.

  print(cherry_prize)
  print(B_prize)
  print(BB_prize)
  print(BBB_prize)
  print(seven_prize)
  print(no_prize)
  print(response)

  # The last function quantifies the jackpot, once it has been reached.
  prize(response)
}
```

Hope I have provided enough information. All help received very gratefully, and hope it can help others.

Comment: `response` doesn't change inside the loop, so the loop can only be infinite (if it is entered)

Comment: Probably you need a `response <- pull()` inside the `while` loop...

Comment: First, loop is resetting to Zero all vectors everytime . To prevent this needs start those vectors before "while" loop starts. Second, if you want the final values as output you need use a output function like `return()` or just call the vector o list of vectors required in place of `print()` function. Finally, `response` variable needs to be changed inside while loop, as @Moody_Mudskipper refers

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the suggestions above. So I followed the instructions and came across a warning that that prevented the function from running.

```
Error in symbols == "DD" : 
comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

So again I think the coding method that I am using is not the most efficient method, but I corrected this with `as.list()`.

```
play2 <- function(){

  runs <- 0
  cherry_prize <- 0
  B_prize <- 0
  BB_prize <- 0
  BBB_prize <- 0
  seven_prize <- 0
  no_prize <- 0

  while (sum(as.list(response) == "DD") != 3) {

    runs <- runs + 1

    response <- pull()

    if ("C" %in% response){
      cherry_prize <- cherry_prize + 1
    }
    else if (sum(as.list(response) == "B") != 3) {
      B_prize <- B_prize + 1
    }
    else if (sum(as.list(response) == "BB") != 3) {
      BB_prize <- BB_prize + 1
    }
    else if (sum(as.list(response) == "BBB") != 3) {
      BBB_prize <- BBB_prize + 1
    }
    else if (sum(as.list(response) == "7") != 3) {
      seven_prize <- seven_prize + 1
    }
    else {
      no_prize <- no_prize + 1
    }
  }
  print(runs)
  print(cherry_prize)
  print(B_prize)
  print(BB_prize)
  print(BBB_prize)
  print(seven_prize)
  print(no_prize)
  print(response)
  score(response)
}
```

This gives the output:

```
> play2()
[1] 430118
[1] 12526
[1] 411199
[1] 6393
[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] "DD" "DD" "DD"
[1] 800
```

Something in part of my code that I haven't shown is affecting my BBB, 7 and no prize.